# Simple way to consistently access a SMB mount?

Tags: networking, filesystem, mount, samba, gui

Is there any simple GUI way to make an SMB share persistent? I don't quite remember the steps, but on Windows, once you've mapped a share to a drive, you're given the option to 'reconnect on boot' (or something like that).

I figure I can just edit `fstab`, but this is something I have less technical users (as in GUI only) wanting to do, and it would be nice if there was some simple way to accomplish this.

*[Note: Edited the title to reflect that while I originally specified 'persistent' for my use, something that's can be consistently accessed is fine.]*

Comment: Yes please, I would love to know this to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you define "persistent" as "user always can click on it" then standard tools will do:

1. Go to "Places -> Connect to Server..."
2. Select "Windows share". Enter connection data.
3. Select "Add bookmark".

Now persistent bookmark will be available on your "Places" menu and on the left navigation panel in file browser (nautilus).

Comment: Perfect, use that for FTP all the time, forgot it would be the same for other network connections.

Comment: This does not mount at boot, it connects when you navigate to the bookmark, it also does not work for other applications trying to access the share. This is not equivalent to editing the fstab.

Comment: @trampster Agreed, however, for my use defining "persistent" as "user always can click on it" is fine. I'll update the title accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Gigolo is an SMB broswer with an 'autoconnect' option when you bookmark a share. Click on the icon to install [gigolo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gigolo) (from Software Center or `sudo apt-get install gigolo`) and it's pretty easy from there.

(Another answer, no extra apps, but it's not perfect: Navigate to the location in Nautilus and Add a Bookmark (Bookmarks -> Add, or CTRL-D). Each login you'll need to navigate to the share to mount it (sorry!), but once you have, it will be mounted in /home/username/.gvfs/ )

Answer (score 1):

even better way is to mount it not as a windows share, but as a local drive which allows for unity searching as explained here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently
navigate to here:
Mounting unprotected (guest) network folders

First, let's create the mount directory. You will need a separate directory for each mount.

sudo mkdir /media/windowsshare

Then edit your /etc/fstab file (with root privileges) to add this line:

//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0

After you add the entry to /etc/fstab type:

sudo mount -a

This will (re)mount all entries listed in /etc/fstab.

Comment: please note this is not working for 12.10 (yet!? - Bug #995535), but is a major feature which I'd like to see fixed very soon.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Go to network.. select disk or enter the smb:/ipnr.. check keep persistent or any term that everyone understands.