# How to get sudo access to shares mounted by Gigolo

Tags: gvfs, fuse, gigolo

As found [around the web](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2012/10/30/auto-mounting-windows-shares-in-gnome-with-gigolo-and-gvfs-fuse/) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/15315/181442), I can use Gigolo to mount a Windows share and even access it through a terminal, via the `~/.gvfs/share on server/` directory, such as:

```
ls ~/.gvfs/share\ on\ server/
```

Unfortunately, when I try to access the same directory from a command via `sudo`, e. g.

```
sudo ls ~/.gvfs/share\ on\ server/
```

which fails with:

```
ls: cannot access /home/user/.gvfs/share\ on\ server/: Permission denied
```

Any suggestions on how to get `sudo` access to existing Gigolo-mounted shares? Or, how to run Gigolo in order to get `sudo` access to the shares?

Answer (score 9):

Gigolo is a frontend to `gvfs`. `gvfs` uses FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) in order to mount network devices (such as Windows shares). Such mountpoints cannot normally be read by other users than the user who mounted it, even by `root`. Why? Karl Auer suggests [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2008-November/165644.html) that the reason is that

> Just because you have root access on one system doesn't mean you should
>   be allowed to see the files to which other people have access on other
>   systems. I'm pretty sure that is why the .gvfs directory is managed the
>   way it is.

That is, if you are user A on machine X, and you mount some directory from machine Y (where you also have a login) to some place on machine X, then `root` on machine X shouldn't be able to read that, because `root` on machine X may not usually have any access to machine Y at all.

Bearing that in mind, if you do want to allow `root` to acces your `~/.gvfs` directory, you can proceed as follows.

1) Edit the file `/etc/fuse.conf` and uncomment the line that reads `#user_allow_other`. This will later allow your user to start the gvfs-fuse daemon with the `allow_root` option, which is what you want. The following command does it quickly for you:

```
$ sudo sed -i -e 's/#user_allow_other/user_allow_other/' /etc/fuse.conf
```

2) Add your own user to the `fuse` group, so that you may read the the file `/etc/fuse.conf`. Otherwise the change in the previous step would have no effect.

```
$ sudo addgroup USERNAME fuse
$ newgrp fuse
```

Replace `USERNAME` with your username, of course. The `newgrp` command avoids the need to log out and back in again for the group change to take effect. Check that it works by issuing the command:

`$ groups`

and verify that `fuse` is listed among the groups that your user belongs to. If it does not work, log out and back in again. At any rate, your user should be able to read `/etc/fuse.conf` before you proceed with the next step.

3) You are now able to restart the gvfs-fuse daemon with the `allow_root` option. First, unmount your `~/.gvfs` directory:

```
$ fusermount -zu $HOME/.gvfs
```

Next, to restart the daemon, issue the following commands on Ubuntu 13.10:

```
$ killall gvfsd-fuse
$ /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse -o allow_root $HOME/.gvfs
```

In older Ubuntu versions, the latter two commands may instead be:

```
$ killall gvfs-fuse-daemon
$ /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-fuse-daemon -o allow_root $HOME/.gvfs
```

4) Restart Gigolo and mount your Windows share again. `root` should now be able to read your `~/.gvfs` directory.

That's it!

**In order to make these changes permanent:**

To make the changes permanent, you can write the three commands from step 3 into a small script that you autostart at login time. There may be cleaner ways to do this, but this should work. Your script would contain something like the following:

```
!#/bin/bash
fusermount -zu $HOME/.gvfs
killall gvfsd-fuse
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse -o allow_root $HOME/.gvfs
```

Save that to a file and make the file executable:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/the/file
```

This script should now be automatically executed at login time. To find out how to autostart applications, refer to [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login).

Some more discussion on the issue can be found here:
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2008-November/165644.html

Comment: Okay, but what if you get the message "group 'fuse' does not exist"? with the addgroup command?

Comment: @Nuzzolilo What Ubuntu version are you using? Also, do you have the package `fuse` installed?

Comment: 15.10, and yes.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/715637/setting-up-gvfsd-to-specify-options-when-autolaunching-gvfsd-fuse

Comment: Ok, which group does the file `/etc/fuse.conf` belong to on your machine? (This should normally be the group `fuse`; use `ls -g /etc/fuse.conf` to find out.) Also, what is the output of the command `grep fuse /etc/group`?

Comment: ls -g /etc/fuse.conf: -rw-r--r-- 1 root 280 Jan  1 02:26 /etc/fuse.conf

Comment: grep fuse /etc/group:
fuse:x:1001:nuzz

Comment: Did you ever create a user or a group called `fuse` yourself? (Note that creating a user `fuse` would implicitly create a group `fuse`.) I ask because your ID of the group `fuse` is 1001 -- IDs from 1000 are used for user-created accounts on Ubuntu systems. Also, what is the output of `grep fuse /etc/passwd`?

Comment: Yes I did create the group myself, as the package did not create it.  Did not create a user as far as I know.  grep fuse /etc/passwd gives no output

Comment: Ok, here's the thing. For some reason your system did not create the group `fuse` and thus did not make `/etc/fuse.conf` belong to the group `fuse`. You created the group, but you also need to change the ownership of the file accordingly to simulate the normal behavior: `sudo chown root:fuse /etc/fuse.conf` will take care of this. According to `/etc/group`, your user `nuzz` is already part of group `fuse`. Please ensure this is indeed the case using the command `groups`. If it does not show `fuse`, try to log out and back in again. Then you should be able to proceed with step 3 of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement on 18.04 where I wanted to allow root to access an android phone mounted in `gvfs` in order to backup files. I thought it would be worth documenting what I did for people googling for a solution. The steps required were taken from `@Malte Skoruppas` answer and modified for 18.04.

On 18.04 the gvfs mount point is at `/run/user/$UID/gvfs` not `$HOME/.gvfs`. In my case UID=1000.

After login the situation is this:

`gvfsd-fuse` is running:

```
$ pgrep gvfsd-fuse -l
1856 gvfsd-fuse
```

The mount exists:

```
$ mount | grep gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

And root does not have permission to read the dir

```
# ls /run/user/1000/gvfs
ls: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
```

A normal user has read permissions for `/etc/fuse.conf` so we do not have to create a fuse group and add our user to it.

```
$ grep allow /etc/fuse.conf
# Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.
# Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options.
user_allow_other
```

To give `root` access I did the following:

```
$ fusermount -zu /var/run/user/1000/gvfs/
$ pkill gvfsd-fuse
$ /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse -o allow_root /var/run/user/1000/gvfs/
$ mount | grep gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000,allow_other)
```

After this root can access the dir.

I do not know why mount shows `allow_other` rather than `allow_root`. If I run `gvfsd-fuse` with `-o allow_other` the behavior is the same.