# network acces from a ubuntu client to servers

Tags: networking, vpn

I use ubuntu 15.04 and absolutely new to this OS. This is first time to use Linux OS as a personal desktop OS. Before that, I used to use windows for years.

Now I was asked by my client to connect his file server with VPN and told pptp connect information(vpn server host's fqdn, account name and password).
I could set pptp network interface settings and saw the network indicator, which is shown the desktop bar, said it was connected to the server.

However I didn't know what to do next. I asked it to the client and he told that he just type 192.168.xxx.xxx, then can see shared folders. That's all he knew. His desktop OS was windows.
I have no idea...

In this case, what should I make sure and do to access the 'shared folders' on the server ?

best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you can ping the Windows server. Open a command prompt and type `ping 192.168.xxx.xxx`.

Once you see replies check out [Simple way to consistently access a SMB mount?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15312/simple-way-to-consistently-access-a-smb-mount)